# Tomcat cant read file that is read locally

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I have this code in my `CacheInitializer` which implements `ServletContextListener`

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("synonyms.txt").getFile());
        if (file != null && file.exists()) {
            try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    String leftHand = line.split("=>")[0];
                    String rightHand = line.split("=>")[1];

                    for (String s : leftHand.split(",")) {
                        if (s.equals(""))
                            continue;
                        synonymsLookupMap.put(s.trim(), rightHand.trim());
                    }
                }
                scanner.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Synonyms file not found");
        }
```

`sysnonyms.txt` file resides inside resources folder. When I try to run this code locally (Mac OSX), it runs perfectly fine. But when I deploy the same war on my Amazon Linux EC2 machine, no contents are read. I tried remote debug and code never enters the while loop. No exception is thrown either. It finds the file but behaves as if its empty, and there are no lines to be read. I tried creating synonyms.txt through vi on server and then using that to see if it was a file format issue. It did not work either.

Any idea what must be the issue?

Comment: Is `synomyms.txt` bundled in the `war` file? If you are sure it is somewhere in the ClassPath and actually exists as a "file", then try printing its absolute path in both the cases. I believe in one case (local) the file actually exists as a file on ClassPath and in another (remote) it doesn't.

Comment: If it is a static file (not a config one), you should make `synonyms.txt` bundle as a part of _relocatable_ war file and read it using `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` method; i.e. read it as a `stream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources are not files. The resource API can deliver you either a URL or an InputStream for the resource. That's all you need. Just construct the Scanner directly from the input stream. The diversion via File is redundant and pointless and will not work.